# Hover on menu disappears when using background slider with position:fixed and z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index, css-position

I found out that the hover effect from the main menu disappears if I want to go to the second menu level. Here you find the example:

http://bfb.bplaced.net/ie/

HTML:

```
<div id="background-slider">
    <a href="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Opera-Background-Blue-Swirls.jpg"></a>
    <a href="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/green-abstract-background.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-level-1">
            <li class="level-1 clearfix">
                <a href="unternehmen.html" class="level-1">Unternehmen</a>
                <ul class="nav-level-2">
                    <li class="level-2"><a href="/unternehmen/die-firma.html" class="level-2">Die Firma</a></li>
                    <li class="level-2"><a href="/unternehmen/das-team.html" class="level-2">Das Team</a></li>
                    <li class="level-2"><a href="/unternehmen/allgemeines.html" class="level-2">Allgemeines</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="script-section" class="hidden">
    <script src="./js/jquery.superbgimage.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Options for SuperBGImage
            $.fn.superbgimage.options = {
                transition: 1,
                speed: 'slow',
                randomtransition: 0,
                slideshow: 1,
                slide_interval: 6000,
                randomimage: 0
            };

            // initialize SuperBGImage
            $('#background-slider').superbgimage().hide;
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 23px;
    bottom: 40px;
}

ul.nav-level-1 {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

ul.nav-level-1 li.level-1 {
    /*float: left;*/
}

ul.nav-level-1 li.level-1 a.level-1 {
    font-family: 'SourceSansProBlack', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123373;
    padding: 0 5px;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s, background-color 0.25s ease 0s;
    float: left;
}

ul.nav-level-1 li.level-1 a.level-1:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123373;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav-level-1 li:hover a {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

ul.nav-level-1 li.level-1:hover ul.nav-level-2 {
    display: block;
}

ul.nav-level-2 {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 390px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

ul.nav-level-2  li.level-2 {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

ul.nav-level-2  li.level-2 a.level-2{
    font-family: 'SourceSansProBold', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123373;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s, background-color 0.25s ease 0s;
}

ul.nav-level-2  li.level-2 a.level-2:hover{
    background-color: #123373;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The slider I'm using is called [SuperBGImage](http://dev.andreaseberhard.de/jquery/superbgimage/). **If I remove the slider everything works!**

I thin it's the z-Index bug of IE but I tried different options by adding `position: relative;` without success. How do I get the hover effect fixed in IE?

I tried this JS code but it doesn't help either:

```
$('li.level-1').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul.nav-level-2').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).children('ul.nav-level-2').addClass('visible');
});
$('ul.nav-level-2').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('visible');
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Perhaps it is a float issue. If I remove `float: left;` than it works better but it is not the design which it should be.

**Edit:**

[Here](http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/24356058/file.html) you can download the project. I noticed another thing. If I start the Internet Explorer he asks me if I want to start the scripts or the Active-X elements. Why does he ask me that? I know it's because the slider but it should be normal Javascript. Perhaps the JS from the slider does something special here ...

Comment: I don't really understand - everything looks OK to me?

Comment: Sorry, missed the tag.

Comment: @testing It is getting tough to test online, can we get a pack of your project?

Comment: I think that was meant for the OP?

Comment: @BenM Oops, I missed that ;)

Comment: I just have a hint for you: Working with `.clearfix:hover` might help for new IEs. I just saw that giving it `background: red` partially fixes your problem (except the red background coming with it). I cannot explain why, it's a mystery.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Here you go: http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/24356058/file.html

Comment: @CedricReichenbach: How do you mean that? Adding `.clearfix:hover` to the `.clearfix:after` definition does not work for me in IE10. `background: red` for `#menu` seems to work much better, but `background: transparent` doesn't work anymore. Bummer!

Comment: I meant `.clearfix:hover` as new rule definition.  Had the same results as you (not working with transparent).

Comment: Typically IE asks you "if [you] want to start the scripts or the Active-X elements" because you are loading a resource from an external location (from Internet) even though the page is being loaded locally (from HDD). Unless the request is denied, this won't cause any problems with a page's operation as it merely delays the processes which normally occur without this authorization step in a regular environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CedricReichenbach brought me on another idea. Adding a transparent background image (1x1) seems to work for IE:

```
.level-1 ul {
    background-image: url(../img/transparent-background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Though will test it more.

Answer (score 5):

I've got it working on IE9 & IE10 ***should also work in IE8***, using transparent background and hovering over `.clearfix`

Check out the updated - **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/PNTcG/30/)**

I changed this-

```
ul.nav-level-1 li.level-1 a.level-1:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123373;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To this-

```
.clearfix:hover ul.nav-level-1, li.level-1, a.level-1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123373;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); /*** TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND FIX ***/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And added height and width to this-

```
.clearfix {
    display:block;
    width:100%;    /* added height and width */
    height:50px;
}
```

for IE7 and below add-

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
 .clearfix:hover ul.nav-level-1, li.level-1, a.level-1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123373;
    background:#ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

The above work around just replaces the transparent rgba with a solid white. It wont be as pretty in ancient IE, but few things ever are.

**Note, that `<nav>` isn't supported in IE8 and below**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would also need this for IE7 and IE8. With jsFiddle the simulator I can't currently test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Position:Absolute it will work :-)

Comment: `position:absolute;` on `#menu`?